# Get value_counts() for values of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I'm very familiar with how to return [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) from a `pd.Series`. However, how would I get the value counts from values of a dictionary?

Say that I have the following tuples in dictionary `L`:

```
L = {1: (13600, 14797),
     2: (14700, 14700),
     3: (14700, 10400),
     4: (14600, 17200),
     5: (13600, 14797),
     6: (14600, 17200),
     7: (14700, 10400),
     8: (14700, 10400),
     9: (12800, 14770)}
```

How do I get the `value_counts` from `L` that would look like:

```
(14700, 10400) 3
(13600, 14797) 2
(14600, 17200) 2
(14700, 14700) 1
(12800, 14770) 1
```

This is what I have so far. However, I think the dictionary keys 1-9 are getting in the way because I get the error `list object is not callable.`

```
list = [(k, v) for k, v in L.items()] 
S = set(L)
F = {}
for i in list(S):
    F[i] = list.count(i)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the standard library:

```
Counter(L.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `from collections import Counter` is a good idea?

```
from collections import Counter 
dict(Counter([j for i,j in L.items()]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
L = {1: (13600, 14797),
     2: (14700, 14700),
     3: (14700, 10400),
     4: (14600, 17200),
     5: (13600, 14797),
     6: (14600, 17200),
     7: (14700, 10400),
     8: (14700, 10400),
     9: (12800, 14770)}
vals = [ v for v in L.values()]
counts = []
for i in vals:
    counts.append((i, vals.count(i)))
set(counts)
```

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned  `pandas.Series.value_counts()`, why did you not try

```
pd.Series(L).value_counts()
```

which gives:

```
(14700, 10400)    3
(14600, 17200)    2
(13600, 14797)    2
(12800, 14770)    1
(14700, 14700)    1
dtype: int64
```